# "true"/"false" value not populated back in Selection xtype - Classic UI Dialog - Adobe AEM/CQ

Tags: aem

I have a classic UI dialog. This has a drop down in dialog which has "true"/"false" as options

```
<mydropdown
      jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
      allowBlank="{Boolean}false"
      fieldLabel="My Dropdown"
      name="./dropdownValue"
      type="select"
      xtype="selection">
      <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
         <test
             jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
             text="True"
             value="true"/>
         <test_x0020_1
             jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
             text="False"
             value="false"/>
          <test_x0020_2
             jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
             text="someothervaluetext"
             value="someothervalue"
       </options>
</mydropdown>
```

The JCR structure is saving value as String "true", "false". When user edits the dialog, the value should be populated back in the field. "true", "false" value is not getting populated, while "someothervalue" works fine.

Checked the **Selection.js** in libs, code below is responsible to populating data in dialog

```
 var count = this.comboBox.store.getTotalCount();
 var i = 0;
 for (; i < count; i++) {
      var data = this.comboBox.store.getAt(i).data;
      if (data.value == this.value) {  // Here data.value is coming as boolean
             this.hiddenField.setValue(data.value);
             this.comboBox.setValue(data.text);
             break;
       }
  }
```

`data.value` is coming as `boolean` though in JCR the value is stored as string. Due to this the condition is evaluating to false and value is not set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked with Adobe Day Care. Adobe confirmed, this is a bug in AEM 6.1. This has been fixed in AEM 6.2. Following is the granite bug reference

> **CQ-64223** - cq:Widget xtype=selection type=select cannot contains option
>   with value "true" and "false"

For earlier versions, hotfix can be requested from Adobe. For my case "1", "0" works for me as I had to evaluate it with angular `ng-if/ng-show`

Comment: It seems to work fine with "TRUE" and "FALSE" (uppercase). Unfortunately Boolean.parseBoolean(“1”) will resolve to false (eg. ValueMap), where as "TRUE" works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The only issue I see is the value of the `name` property. Generally the name is prefixed with `./` so that the property and its corresponding value is set on the node. When the name doesn't start with `./` it is omitted.

Try this and it should work.

```
name="./dropdownValue"
```

[Sling Post Servlet documentation](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/manipulating-content-the-slingpostservlet-servlets-post.html#omitting-some-parameters) explains more on how the Sling Post Servlet works.

Comment: Thanks Rakhi for your response. I checked on this. Actually the dropdown was part of custom multifield, so the ./ was not there. I tried placing the dropdown outside custom multifield with ./ Same behaviour "true", "false" values are not populated back, while "someothervalue" is populated back fine. Updated the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: In that case, you may need to add more information to the question regarding the custom multifield implementation. Else it would be difficult to answer the question, because it would work fine otherwise.

Comment: Checked more on this, added code responsible for populating data. Not sure if it is a bug in AEM. Just tried to use "1", "0" as value instead of "true", "false". That is populated back fine.